# How to create dll using gcc compiler/Mingw for visual basic?

Tags: dll, gcc, mingw

How to create dll using gcc compiler/Mingw for visual basic?

Comment: What Visual Basic version? What technology do you want to use in VB to call dll: COM or API calls/PInvoke?

Answer (score 9):

The following is how I was able to get MinGW to build a DLL to be used in Excel 2003 VBA.

**fooBar.cpp**

```
int __stdcall Foo(int x)   
{   
    return x * x;   
}

double __stdcall Bar(double x)   
{   
    return x * x;   
}
```

1) Start MinGW shell and create a directory called `fooBar` .
Close the Excel Workbook (if open).

```
mkdir -p fooBar
cd fooBar
rm *.a *.dll *.def
```

2) Compile and generate a .def file - ***Note: this dll will not work because it has mangled symbols.***

```
gcc -shared -o fooBar.dll fooBar.cpp -Wl,--output-def,fooBar.def,--out-implib,libfooBardll.a
```

The generated fooBar.def will look something like:

```
EXPORTS
    _Z3Bard@8 @1
    _Z3Fooi@4 @2
```

3) Modify the generated fooBar.def file by adding clean symbol aliases for the generated symbols. fooBar.def should now look something like:

```
EXPORTS
    _Z3Bard@8 @1
    _Z3Fooi@4 @2
    Bar = _Z3Bard@8
    Foo = _Z3Fooi@4
```

4) Cleaup again (except for the modified fooBar.def)

```
rm *.a *.dll
```

5) Compile with .def file with clean symbol aliases for the generated symbols.

```
gcc -shared -o fooBar.dll fooBar.cpp fooBar.def -Wl,--out-implib,libfooBar_dll.a
```

6) Open Excel and add the following VBA code ***(make sure to use the proper path, doubt it will have mmorris in it)***:

```
Private Declare Function Foo Lib _
    "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\mmorris\fooBar\fooBar.dll" _
    (ByVal x As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function Bar Lib _
    "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\mmorris\fooBar\fooBar.dll" _
    (ByVal x As Double) As Double
```

7) If you want to call the functions from an Excel Workbook, in a cell type `=Foo(5)` or `=Bar(5)`

Answer (score 3):

First some DLL-iquette:

All exported function should have C linkage.
All C++-exceptions thrown inside the DLL should be catched inside the dll.

Why? Because there is no standard C++ ABI on Windows.

Also use __declspec(dllexport) on functions that should be exported

Now how to make the DLL without needing any DEF file

**fooBar.cpp**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall square_int(int x) //I prefer manual mangling in this case to support static polymorphism
    {   
        return x * x;   
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall square_double(double x)   
    {   
        return x * x;   
    }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

compile using

```
gcc fooBar.cpp -shared -Wl,--kill-at -o fooBar.dll
```

Now you should be able to call square_xxx as in mmorris answer. His solution probably works though.

Comment: This compiled, but it did not work in Excel.  The advice by mmorris works, but this looks like a better implementation.  Perhaps a version of mingw gcc version problem?  This method is something I should beat my head over because it appears to be a more elegant solution.  Thanks.

Comment: @RJB I have not tried my self, but perhaps excel does not recognize '_'

Answer (score 1):

This: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/DLL might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

VB (all versions) prefers the pascal calling convention.

Declare your external functions with WINAPI and export them in your .def file.